# What are the rules for standard protocols path?

Tags: javascript, electron, url-scheme

I can't understand how the path resolution work in electron when you register a custom protocol as standard.

I have a basic custom protocol for app folder's files:

```
protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([
  { scheme: 'app', privileges: {
                standard: true,
                secure: true,
                supportFetchAPI: true,
                corsEnabled: true,
                bypassCSP: true
            } }
])
app.on('ready', e=> {

    protocol.registerFileProtocol('app', 
                (i,o)=> console.log(i.url)||
                        o({path: path.resolve(__dirname, i.url)})
    )
    let win = new BrowserWindow()
    win.loadURL(`app://tabbed-window.html`)

}
```

```html
    <script type="module" src="utils/DOM.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" 
          href="/components/Window.html" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="./components/Tab.css" />


    <link rel="import" 
          href="../components/icon.html" 
            data-="themes/icons/app.svg" 
            data-fas="themes/icons/fa-solid.svg" 
            data-far="themes/icons/fa-regular.svg"
            data-fab="themes/icons/fa-brands.svg" />
```

On the logs I have a leading slash after the main .html file so the nested ressources relatives path are wrong, getting the html file as a folder, whatever how each file is request (`./` `/` even `../` don't avoid the .html/ folder !! )

```
{
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'app://tabbed-window.html/',
  referrer: '',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
  }
}
{
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'app://tabbed-window.html/utils/DOM.js',
  referrer: '',
  headers: {
    Origin: 'app://tabbed-window.html',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) termos/0.3.0 Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Electron/8.2.3 Safari/537.36',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'script',
    Accept: '*/*'
  }
}
{
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'app://tabbed-window.html/components/Window.html',
  referrer: '',
  headers: {
    Origin: 'app://tabbed-window.html',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) termos/0.3.0 Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Electron/8.2.3 Safari/537.36',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'unknown',
    Accept: '*/*'
  }
}
{
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'app://tabbed-window.html/components/Tab.css',
  referrer: '',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) termos/0.3.0 Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Electron/8.2.3 Safari/537.36',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'style',
    Accept: 'text/css,*/*;q=0.1'
  }
}
{
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'app://tabbed-window.html/components/icon.html',
  referrer: '',
  headers: {
    Origin: 'app://tabbed-window.html',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) termos/0.3.0 Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Electron/8.2.3 Safari/537.36',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'unknown',
    Accept: '*/*'
  }
}
```

Comment: I find it difficult to understand what exactly you're trying to achieve, and therefore also to understand what's going wrong. Could you add some context?

Comment: I want to have a custom protocol for my app's file starting with "app://" and resolving to the app folder, and relative pathes in the loaded content to be relative to the folder not the loaded file:
`<script src="my-script.js">` should resolve to `appFolder/my-script.js` not `appFolder/the-embedding.html/my-script.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper [URL Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax) is roughly `scheme://host/path`. So, you miss the `host` part. Use something like

```js
win.loadURL(`app://localhost/tabbed-window.html`)
```

And strip the `app://localhost/` prefix in the protocol handler.

Comment: I could figure out this host part missing several month ago, but thanks! ^^;
All the documentation exemples for an `app://` protocol are with non standard scheme...
I mark as answer for the community tought..

Answer (score -1):

The custom protocols in Electron have the same effect as the file:// protocol, wherein files are served from the local file system rather than the relative app path.

To sum up, when you use relative paths (../../), the URL is altered relative to your local filesystem, like so: file:///absolute/path/to/file. The absolute path uses the base href path (in case of angular).

The requests directed to your assets can be intercepted using intercept methods of the protocol api.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but you didn't answer about standard protocols...  
`protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged(  .... privileges: { standard: true } )`